# Equivalent to javax.swing.Timer in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer

Is there something that looks like the `javax.swing.Timer` on Android. I know how to create own Threads, but is there something that is like the swing-timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also Java's TimerTask. Here's an example from my code where I'm playing audio samples:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

// from constructor, shown here out of place
timer = new Timer();

// and in method, again, shown out of place:
        INTERVAL_MILLISECONDS = (int)((double)(bufSize) / (double)(nativeSampleRate * 2) * 1000);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                        synchronized(this){
                                track.write(data, 0, bufSize);
                                track.play();
                        }
                }
        }, 0, INTERVAL_MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 6):

You are probably looking for the class [`android.os.CountDownTimer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

You can inherit the class like this:

```
class MyTimer extends CountDownTimer
{
    public MyTimer(int secsInFuture) {
        super(secsInFuture*1000, 1000); //interval/ticks each second.
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        Log.d("mytag","timer finished!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        //fired on each interval
        Log.d("mytag","tick; " + millisUntilFinished + " ms left");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The main point of `javax.swing.Timer` is that it executes tasks on GUI thread (EDT - event dispatching thread). This makes it safe to manipulate Swing components.

In Android there is also EDT and you should only [manipulate GUI elements on EDT](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html). To delay your code and then run it on EDT use [`view.postDelayed(runnable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29).

Answer (score 0):

The following code correctly handles (1) calling task on GUI thread, (2) not flooding GUI thread when task takes longer than delay time, (3) garbage collection when timer is stopped:

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class ActionEvent {
    public ActionEvent(Object src) {

    }
}

interface ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e);
}

class Timer {
    public Timer(int delay, ActionListener al) {
        addActionListener(al);
        _delay = delay;
    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener al) {
        _listeners.add(al);
    }

    private void fireActionPerformed() {
        for (ActionListener al : _listeners.toArray(new ActionListener[0])) {
            al.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this));
        }
    }

    private void fireAfterDelay() {
        if (!_bStarted)
            return;
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (_bStarted) {
                    fireActionPerformed();
                    if (_bStarted)
                        fireAfterDelay();
                }
            }
        }, _delay);
    }

    public void start() {
        if (!_bStarted) {
            _bStarted = true;
            fireAfterDelay();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        _bStarted = false;
    }

    private final ArrayList<ActionListener> _listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    private int _delay;
    private boolean _bStarted;
}
```

I put in classes ActionEvent and ActionListener for more compatibility with Java Swing.  For simplicity you could remove ActionEvent and replace ActionListener with Runnable.