# NoClassDefFoundError javax.swing.Timer jre7 library vanishes from Java Build Path on eclipse restart

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I'm getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` when I use `javax.swing.Timer`.

I've added the JRE in installed JREs as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181142/eclipse-doesnt-find-javax-swing). I then added the library into the projects java build path and ticked the library in the order and export tab (not sure if that was needed). I am able to import the method but when I run the project I get the error.

```
04-13 11:56:06.896: E/AndroidRuntime(4139): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.swing.Timer
```

When I restart eclipse I notice the jre7 library is no longer in the projects build path.

Not sure if the problem is related to the `eclipse.ini` file or the project's `.classpath` file. I've tried project clean etc but cant find a solution online. I even tried adding the rt.jar from jre7 as external jar but then the project failed to launch. Everything else works, I just cant use swing methods.

eclipse.ini

```
    -startup
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
    --launcher.library
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
    -product
    org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
    --launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
    --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
    256M
    -showsplash
    org.eclipse.platform
    --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
    256m
    --launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
    --launcher.appendVmargs
    -vmargs
    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
    -Xms40m
    -Xmx512m
```

.classpath

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con"        path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con"         path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
    </classpath>
```

Comment: See this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7260074/230513).